# Is there an easy way to tell JSVGComponent to scale SVG image to fit the preferred size?

Tags: java, swing, batik

I tried setting the preferred size, but the SVG image stays the same. Same if I set the size as well. Furthermore, if it does not fit, then nothing is rendered. Batik only has Javadoc and few pages about the architecture.

What I am working on is simple - I have chess pieces as SVG images (100x100 px) and I want to place them inside 8x8 JSVGComponents that dynamically resize to fit the window. I want SVG images to scale to fit the JSVGComponents they are in.

Comment: Does `GridLayout(8, 8)` work?

Comment: Question is not how to lay out the components, but how to scale SVG image to fit the JSVGComponent's visible box.

Comment: Oh, I thought an SVG would scale automatically. Did you look at [`JSVGCanvas`](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/swing.html)?